# Can't send email with plus symbol (SmtpClient.Send() method from System.Net.Mail)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, smtpclient, system.net.mail

Can the SmtpClient.Send() method from System.Net.Mail really not send to email addresses that have plus symbols in them? I am sending to a list of email addresses and they all get sent except the ones that contain a plus (+) symbol.  Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully send emails to recipients with a + char in the address using `System.Net.Mail` with .net 4.

In my case, the recipients are gmail addresses, where the + and any chars after it don't change the recipient. So `something+somethingelse@gmail.com` sends an email that is received by the `something@gmail.com` account.  But that account can see that it was sent to `something+somethingelse`.

I think this is actually a sendmail standard, not just google stuff. It comes in handy.

**EDIT**: I found some sendmail documentation on "plussed accounts":

http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/misc_features.html

> Sometimes it is convenient to merge configuration on a centralized mail machine, for example, to forward all root mail to a mail server. In this case it might be useful to be able to treat the root addresses as a class of addresses with subtle differences. You can do this using plussed users. For example, a client might include the alias:
>
> root:  root+client1@server
>
> On the server, this will match an alias for "root+client1". If that is not found, the alias "root+*" will be tried, then "root".